# Parse XML namespace format in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml file that looks like that and I want to parse as a regular XML, tryng to loop the values, in particular the `Cell` value.

```
<APIReport xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Rochester.Models">
<Column xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:string>Name</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>Surname</d2p1:string>
</Column>
<Dates>29-04-2016, 00:00:00 - 29-04-2016, 23:59:59</Dates>
<Id>1200</Id>
<Row>
    <APIReportRow>
        <Cell xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d4p1:string>Francesco</d4p1:string>
            <d4p1:string>Delolli</d4p1:string>
        </Cell>
    </APIReportRow>
    <APIReportRow>
        <Cell xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d4p1:string>Roberto</d4p1:string>
            <d4p1:string>Delolli</d4p1:string>
        </Cell>
    </APIReportRow>
</Row>
<Title>Nomi</Title>
```

So I tried to parse it in PHP with SimpleXML, using this simple code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
print_r($xml);
```

But the `Cell` values are empty:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Column] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [Dates] => 29-04-2016, 00:00:00 - 29-04-2016, 23:59:59
    [Id] => 1200
    [Row] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [APIReportRow] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Cell] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Cell] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [Title] => Nomi
)
```

My question is simple: how may I get the `Cell` value of the XML?

Comment: Have you tried to access directly to some Cell node value? Something like: echo (string) $xml->Row->APIReportRow[0]->Cell;

Comment: The cell values are not empty, `print_r` just can't cope with SimpleXML's awesomeness :P The key to accessing the elements inside the `Cell` is that they use "namespaces" (the tags with `:` in them). For that, you need [the `children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

Comment: Duplicate: [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @IMSoP, I got the solution:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$rows = $xml->Row->APIReportRow;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cell = $row->Cell->children('d4p1', true);
    echo "Name: " . (string) $cell->string[0] . "\n";
    echo "Surname: " . (string) $cell->string[1] . "\n";
}
```