# How can I update odrl ( like xml ) file, with new values?

Tags: php, xml

I have this file in odrl (like xml specificly for licenses)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<o-ex:rights
    xmlns:o-ex="licences/ODRL-EX-11"
    xmlns:o-dd="licences/ODRL-DD-11"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ie-ex="licences/ieee1599-EX"
 >
      <!-- agreementS -->
<o-ex:agreement>
  <o-ex:permission o-ex:id="permission_audio">
    <o-dd:play>

      <o-ex:constraint o-ex:id="constraint_quality">
        <ie-ex:qualityOfResource value="medium"/>
      </o-ex:constraint>        
          <o-dd:datetime>
              <o-dd:start>2017-08-16</o-dd:start>
                <o-dd:end>2017-10-20</o-dd:end>
          </o-dd:datetime>
      </o-ex:constraint>
  </o-dd:play>

</o-ex:permission>
</o-ex:agreement>
```

How can I update my file with new values? 
example:

```
<o-dd:start>2018-04-15</o-dd:start>
```

Comment: This isn't "like XML", it *is* XML. You can use any XML tool you want. See http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php for what PHP provides out the box (in particular check out the SimpleXML and DOM sections), or search online. Voting to close as Too Broad.

Comment: i have tried to use  SimpleXML e DOM and dom but the problem are prefix like o-ex: or o-dd.

Comment: In that case, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si (I would mark this question as a duplicate, but can't change my existing close vote.)