# Missing Attributes while parsing XML with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($value);
$json = json_encode($xml); // convert the XML string to JSON
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Attributes are missing after converting into array.

Comment: Can you include the content of $value and what you are trying to achieve.  It may be better to learn to work with SimpleXML as it's directly working with the source data rather than a processed version of this data.

Comment: Oh, here is the api URL where i'm trying to parse XML with in XML: https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=biosample&id=367368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<SampleData>` value as you say is encoded, the simplest way to get this back to 'normal' is to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to convert all the symbols before loading the string into `SimpleXML`.  The code below does this and then outputs various parts of the data as an example of how to display information...

```
$source = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=biosample&id=367368";
$value = file_get_contents($source);
$value = htmlspecialchars_decode($value);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($value);
// Access the DbBuild value
echo "DbBuild=".(string)$xml->DocumentSummarySet->DbBuild.PHP_EOL;
// The BioSample publication date attribute
echo "BioSample publication date=".(string)$xml->DocumentSummarySet->DocumentSummary->SampleData->BioSample['publication_date'].PHP_EOL;
// List the attributes name and value
foreach ( $xml->DocumentSummarySet->DocumentSummary->SampleData->BioSample->Attributes->Attribute as $attribute )   {
    echo (string)$attribute['attribute_name']."=".(string)$attribute.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Some of the XML access looks long winded, but it's just a case of accessing the various levels of data in the document.  `$xml->DocumentSummarySet` accesses the `<DocumentSummarySet>` element under the root elements.  `BioSample['publication_date']` is the publication_date attribute in the `<BioSample>` element and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple solution to this - delete these two lines of code:

```
$json = json_encode($xml); // convert the XML string to JSON
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

XML, JSON, and PHP arrays all have different rules about what kind of structures can be represented, so converting arbitrarily between them will *always* end up with edge cases where you're missing data. SimpleXML is, as the name says, designed to be *simple to use*, so you will be much better off actually using it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($value);
// Now access your data from $xml; no further conversion is needed
```

Since you give no further information about what your XML looks like, I can't give any further information about how to process it, but there are [extensive examples in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), and [refer here if there are namespaces (tags or attributes with `:` in their name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si).