# replace an invalid URI in the .xml file

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing, simplexml

how can i replace an invalid URI in xml file, i cannot parse the xml file because it gives an invalid URI error while trying to parse the file. How can i read the contents of the .xml file into a string so that the invalid URI can be replaced.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<Submit xmlns="http://localhost/....">
    <Order>
    <Components>
        <Component>
            <ocode> ABC</ocode>
        </Component>
    </Components>
</Order>
</Submit>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is this a SOAP response? If so, have you considered using SoapClient instead of cURL or however you're getting it? It may be handier than dealing directly with the XML yourself. Just a suggestion. :-)

Comment: I don't have direct access to the soap response, i can only work with the xml file that  is created.So basically i am trying to read the .xml file to get one of the node value.

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate, but it should still be doable. Most likely an issue with the namespace. Can you show the code you're currently using and the error you're getting?

Comment: I was just trying to see if i can read the xml using simplexml_load_file, but i get an error $xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
print_r($xml);

Comment: namespace error : xmlns: 'http://localhost/....' is not a valid URI

Comment: I think we have an "X/Y Problem" here: you have asked how to remove the `soap:envelope` and `soap:body`, but your actual problem is "how do I avoid this parsing error?" As worded, this question could be considered a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si but that probably wouldn't help answer your actual problem. Please [edit] the question to clarify that your actual problem is the "namespace error" message - making sure you include the full text of the message and a [mcve] for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i have changed the question to explain the exact problem that i am having and what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the content, use SimpleXML and XPath to fetch the body contents...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("NewFile.xml"); 
$content = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body/*");
echo $content[0]->Order->asXML();
```

will give...

```
<Order>
    <Components>
        <Component>
            <ocode> ABC</ocode>
        </Component>
    </Components>
</Order>
```

Not sure what the namespace `http://localhost/....` is supposed to be, but it should be a valid URI - even if it is `http://localhost`.

**Edit:**

To try and fix the URI, you can read the file to a string first and then replace the invalid string with a valid one...

```
$data = file_get_contents("NewFile.xml");
$data = str_replace("http://localhost/....", "http://localhost", $data);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($data);
```

Or you could also try removing all of the attributes...

```
$data = preg_replace("/<Submit.*?>/", "<Submit>", $data);
```

Comment: It errors out on line simplexml_load_file, how can i replace the invalid uri from the .xml file.

Comment: I've added some new code, you can process the string before loading it.

Comment: how can i see the output of the changed xml, when i do print_r it gives blank object and when i do echo $xml->asxml() it just displays all the values, not as an xml or an array. I tried to access the ocode as $xml->Order->Components->Component->ocode but does not display anything.

Comment: If you are using a `echo $xml->asxml()` to a browser, you may have to view source to see the full XML.

Comment: Thank you :) @Nigel Ren