# PHP, Convert iTunes RSS to JSON

Tags: php, json, rss, simplexml

I am trying to utilize simplexml to convert an iTunes RSS Feed to JSON so I can better parse it. The issue I am having is that it is not coming back as correctly formatted JSON.

```
$feed_url = 'https://podcasts.subsplash.com/c2yjpyh/podcast.rss';
$feed_contents = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed_contents); 
$podcasts = json_decode(json_encode($xml));

print_r($podcasts);
```

Is there a better way to be attempting this to get the correct result?

Comment: Rather than converting it into JSON (or, as you show here, into a PHP array), why not just use the SimpleXML object as intended? You'll probably need to understand [how to use namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si) but once you've got the hang of that, you'll wonder why you ever thought arrays were a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to IMSoP for pointing me in the right direction! This took a bit of studying but the solution ends up being very simple! Instead of trying to convert to a JSON format, just use SimpleXML. However, due to the namespaces, it does require an additional line to map the itunes: prefix.

So in my iTunes feed rss, the following line exists: `xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd` So we just reference this to make accessing the values very easy.  Here is a quick example:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('https://podcasts.example.com/podcast.rss'); 
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item){

  // Now we define the map for the itunes: namespace
  $itunes = $item->children('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');

  // This is a value WITHOUT the itunes: namespace
  $title = $item->title;

  // This is a value WITH the itunes: namespace
  $author = $itunes->author;

  echo $title . '<br>';
  echo $author . '<br>';

}
```

The other little issue that I ran into is getting attributes such as the url for images and audio links. That is accomplished by using the `attributes()` function like so:

```
// Access attributes WITH itunes: namespace
$image = $itunes->image->attributes();

// Access attributes WITHOUT itunes: namespace
$audio = $item->enclosure->attributes();

// To echo these we simple add the desired attribute in `[]`:
echo $image['href'] . '<br>';
echo $audio['url'] . '<br>';
```