# parsing xml tags with itunes:something from url

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm struggling with parsing xml from url with simplexml_load_file PHP. I found many examples here on stackoverflow but no one gave me the result I expect.

**This is a part of the xml url.**
What I would like to get is **itunes:image or google:image tag**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rss.xslt" ?>
<rss
    xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
    xmlns:googleplay="http://www.google.com/schemas/play-podcasts/1.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:spotify="http://www.spotify.com/ns/rss"
    xmlns:psc="http://podlove.org/simple-chapters/"
    xmlns:media="https://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>"Anecdotes"</title>
                    <link>https://podcast.ausha.co/anecdotes</link>
                <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz"/>
        <description>"Anecdotes" met en lumière des histoires insolites et incroyables, de personnalités connues, ou non, et dont on va pouvoir tirer ensemble, 3 leçons sur la vie, le travail ou l'entrepreneuriat. 
Bonjour, je suis Baptiste Piocelle, entrepreneur, co-fondateur de Canoa et podcasteur. Dans mon émission, vous découvrirez des histoires extraordinaires qui vous feront progresser dans vos objectifs de vie. Identifiez-vous facilement aux invités avec un panel très large de personnalités, de métiers et de caractères. Une émission sans langue de bois ni montage, la vérité à l'état pur. 
Écoutez des personnalités connues raconter des Anecdotes inédites sur leur vie, puis écoutez votre voisin parler de l'histoire incroyable qui lui est arrivé, le choix est votre. 
N'hésitez pas à aimer, noter, partager et commenter le podcast. Si vous le partagez à 3 personnes autour de vous, ensemble, nous atteindrons des sommets. 
Merci et bonne écoute !
Amicalement vôtre, 

Baptiste Piocelle</description>
        <language>fr</language>
        <copyright>Baptiste Piocelle</copyright>
        <lastBuildDate>Sun, 25 Apr 2021 08:01:04 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <pubDate>Sun, 25 Apr 2021 08:01:04 +0000</pubDate>
        <webMaster>feeds@ausha.co (Ausha)</webMaster>
        <generator>Ausha (https://www.ausha.co)</generator>
                    <spotify:countryOfOrigin>fr</spotify:countryOfOrigin>
        
        <itunes:author>Baptiste Piocelle</itunes:author>
        <itunes:owner>
            <itunes:name>Baptiste Piocelle</itunes:name>
            <itunes:email>baptiste.piocelle@gmail.com</itunes:email>
        </itunes:owner>
        <itunes:summary>"Anecdotes" met en lumière des histoires insolites et incroyables, de personnalités connues, ou non, et dont on va pouvoir tirer ensemble, 3 leçons sur la vie, le travail ou l'entrepreneuriat. 
Bonjour, je suis Baptiste Piocelle, entrepreneur, co-fondateur de Canoa et podcasteur. Dans mon émission, vous découvrirez des histoires extraordinaires qui vous feront progresser dans vos objectifs de vie. Identifiez-vous facilement aux invités avec un panel très large de personnalités, de métiers et de caractères. Une émission sans langue de bois ni montage, la vérité à l'état pur. 
Écoutez des personnalités connues raconter des Anecdotes inédites sur leur vie, puis écoutez votre voisin parler de l'histoire incroyable qui lui est arrivé, le choix est votre. 
N'hésitez pas à aimer, noter, partager et commenter le podcast. Si vous le partagez à 3 personnes autour de vous, ensemble, nous atteindrons des sommets. 
Merci et bonne écoute !
Amicalement vôtre, 

Baptiste Piocelle</itunes:summary>
        <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
        <itunes:type>episodic</itunes:type>
                    <itunes:subtitle>Anecdotes insolites et incroyables de personnes connues, ou non.</itunes:subtitle>
        
        <googleplay:author>Baptiste Piocelle</googleplay:author>
        <googleplay:email>baptiste.piocelle@gmail.com</googleplay:email>
        <googleplay:description>"Anecdotes" met en lumière des histoires insolites et incroyables, de personnalités connues, ou non, et dont on va pouvoir tirer ensemble, 3 leçons sur la vie, le travail ou l'entrepreneuriat. 
Bonjour, je suis Baptiste Piocelle, entrepreneur, co-fondateur de Canoa et podcasteur. Dans mon émission, vous découvrirez des histoires extraordinaires qui vous feront progresser dans vos objectifs de vie. Identifiez-vous facilement aux invités avec un panel très large de personnalités, de métiers et de caractères. Une émission sans langue de bois ni montage, la vérité à l'état pur. 
Écoutez des personnalités connues raconter des Anecdotes inédites sur leur vie, puis écoutez votre voisin parler de l'histoire incroyable qui lui est arrivé, le choix est votre. 
N'hésitez pas à aimer, noter, partager et commenter le podcast. Si vous le partagez à 3 personnes autour de vous, ensemble, nous atteindrons des sommets. 
Merci et bonne écoute !
Amicalement vôtre, 

Baptiste Piocelle</googleplay:description>
        <googleplay:explicit>no</googleplay:explicit>

                    <category>Business</category>
            <itunes:category text="Business">
                <itunes:category text="Entrepreneurship"/>
            </itunes:category>
            <googleplay:category text="Business"/>
        
                    <image>
                <url>https://image.ausha.co/XhB165o4xydsexMnRaeWnChVEQyzCCCHesge5RBF_1400x1400.jpeg?t=1606905283</url>
                <title>"Anecdotes"</title>
                                    <link>https://podcast.ausha.co/anecdotes</link>
                            </image>
            <itunes:image href="https://image.ausha.co/XhB165o4xydsexMnRaeWnChVEQyzCCCHesge5RBF_1400x1400.jpeg?t=1606905283"/>
            <googleplay:image href="https://image.ausha.co/XhB165o4xydsexMnRaeWnChVEQyzCCCHesge5RBF_1400x1400.jpeg?t=1606905283"/>
        
                    <item>
                <title>#18 "J'ai tout plaqué du jour au lendemain pour partir seule, j'ai torpillé ma vie." Camille Dubois-Leipp, fondatrice de Outtrip.</title>
                <guid isPermaLink="false">049ecaaadeaca289eb4975b02eee9edb1b8c4792</guid>
                <description><![CDATA[<p>Cela vous est-il déjà arrivé d'imaginer ce qu'il se passerait si vous plaquiez tout du jour au lendemain ? Avec pour objectif de partir vivre seul dans une nouvelle ville, ou bien même pour partir en pèlerinage sur le chemin de Saint-Jacques de Compostelle ?</p>
<p>Et bien si vous voulez une réponse, écoutez cet épisode. Camille Dubois-Leipp a torpillé sa vie du jour au lendemain, pour partir seule, pendant 40 jours, en pèlerinage.</p>
<p>Elle était la cadre dynamique parisienne parfaite, 30 ans, un gros poste, un bon salaire, des amis et du boulot par-dessus la tête.</p>
<p>Puis, tout s'effondre, le déclique, elle part, d'abord sur le chemin de Compostelle, puis elle plaque tout pour s'installer à Annecy, sans argent et sans connaissances.</p>
<p>Aujourd’hui, elle se lance dans l'entrepreneuriat, avec un projet sportif Outtrip.</p>
<p>Un épisode dans lequel on parle de sport, de travail, de spiritualité, de notre rapport à la vie. Bref, un épisode passionnant, que je vous conseille vivement.</p>
<p>N'oubliez pas de vous abonner, c'est super important, et partagez de force ce podcast à vos proches !</p>
<p>Venez me suivre sur instagram @thebatoux et @anecdotes_podcast, ainsi que sur LinkedIn.</p>
<p>À la semaine prochaine !</p>]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Cela vous est-il déjà arrivé d'imaginer ce qu'il se passerait si vous plaquiez tout du jour au lendemain ? Avec pour objectif de partir vivre seul dans une nouvelle ville, ou bien même pour partir en pèlerinage sur le chemin de Saint-Jacques de Compostelle ?</p>
<p>Et bien si vous voulez une réponse, écoutez cet épisode. Camille Dubois-Leipp a torpillé sa vie du jour au lendemain, pour partir seule, pendant 40 jours, en pèlerinage.</p>
<p>Elle était la cadre dynamique parisienne parfaite, 30 ans, un gros poste, un bon salaire, des amis et du boulot par-dessus la tête.</p>
<p>Puis, tout s'effondre, le déclique, elle part, d'abord sur le chemin de Compostelle, puis elle plaque tout pour s'installer à Annecy, sans argent et sans connaissances.</p>
<p>Aujourd’hui, elle se lance dans l'entrepreneuriat, avec un projet sportif Outtrip.</p>
<p>Un épisode dans lequel on parle de sport, de travail, de spiritualité, de notre rapport à la vie. Bref, un épisode passionnant, que je vous conseille vivement.</p>
<p>N'oubliez pas de vous abonner, c'est super important, et partagez de force ce podcast à vos proches !</p>
<p>Venez me suivre sur instagram @thebatoux et @anecdotes_podcast, ainsi que sur LinkedIn.</p>
<p>À la semaine prochaine !</p>]]></content:encoded>
                <pubDate>Sun, 25 Apr 2021 08:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
                <enclosure url="https://audio.ausha.co/yEXw1UR2qKmV.mp3?t=1619332909" length="81096723" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                                    <link>https://podcast.ausha.co/anecdotes/18-j-ai-tout-plaque-du-jour-au-lendemain-pour-partir-seule-j-ai-torpille-ma-vie-camille-dubois-leipp-fondatrice-de</link>
                
                                <itunes:author>Baptiste Piocelle</itunes:author>
                <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
                                    <itunes:keywords>podcast,France,paris,anecdotes,vie,entrepreneuriat,entrepreneur,coach,Rouen,start-up,français,célébrités</itunes:keywords>
                                <itunes:duration>1:24:28</itunes:duration>
                <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
                                    <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
                                            <itunes:episode>16</itunes:episode>
                                                    <itunes:block>no</itunes:block>
                <itunes:subtitle>Cela vous est-il déjà arrivé d'imaginer ce qu'il se passerait si vous plaquiez tout du jour au lendemain ? Avec pour objectif de partir vivre seul dans une nouvelle ville, ou bien même pour partir en pèlerinage sur le chemin de Saint-Jacques de Compost...</itunes:subtitle>

                <googleplay:author>Baptiste Piocelle</googleplay:author>
                                <googleplay:explicit>no</googleplay:explicit>
                <googleplay:block>no</googleplay:block>

                                    <itunes:image href="https://image.ausha.co/RWtgTlFC7BbehBR0KAv5z7HnXXb32yCAFFCw7IbE_1400x1400.jpeg?t=1619332719"/>
                    <googleplay:image href="https://image.ausha.co/RWtgTlFC7BbehBR0KAv5z7HnXXb32yCAFFCw7IbE_1400x1400.jpeg?t=1619332719"/>
                
                
                            </item>
                    <item>
```

**Here the php I'm using to parse**

```
$url = "https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rss);
echo '</pre>';
```

**here what the print_r giving me**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => "Anecdotes"
            [link] => https://podcast.ausha.co/anecdotes
            [description] => "Anecdotes" met en lumière des histoires insolites et incroyables, de personnalités connues, ou non, et dont on va pouvoir tirer ensemble, 3 leçons sur la vie, le travail ou l'entrepreneuriat. 
Bonjour, je suis Baptiste Piocelle, entrepreneur, co-fondateur de Canoa et podcasteur. Dans mon émission, vous découvrirez des histoires extraordinaires qui vous feront progresser dans vos objectifs de vie. Identifiez-vous facilement aux invités avec un panel très large de personnalités, de métiers et de caractères. Une émission sans langue de bois ni montage, la vérité à l'état pur. 
Écoutez des personnalités connues raconter des Anecdotes inédites sur leur vie, puis écoutez votre voisin parler de l'histoire incroyable qui lui est arrivé, le choix est votre. 
N'hésitez pas à aimer, noter, partager et commenter le podcast. Si vous le partagez à 3 personnes autour de vous, ensemble, nous atteindrons des sommets. 
Merci et bonne écoute !
Amicalement vôtre, 

Baptiste Piocelle
            [language] => fr
            [copyright] => Baptiste Piocelle
            [lastBuildDate] => Sun, 25 Apr 2021 08:01:04 +0000
            [pubDate] => Sun, 25 Apr 2021 08:01:04 +0000
            [webMaster] => feeds@ausha.co (Ausha)
            [generator] => Ausha (https://www.ausha.co)
            [category] => Business
            [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [url] => https://image.ausha.co/XhB165o4xydsexMnRaeWnChVEQyzCCCHesge5RBF_1400x1400.jpeg?t=1606905283
                    [title] => "Anecdotes"
                    [link] => https://podcast.ausha.co/anecdotes
                )

            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => #18 "J'ai tout plaqué du jour au lendemain pour partir seule, j'ai torpillé ma vie." Camille Dubois-Leipp, fondatrice de Outtrip.
                            [guid] => 049ecaaadeaca289eb4975b02eee9edb1b8c4792
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [pubDate] => Sun, 25 Apr 2021 08:00:00 +0000
                            [enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://audio.ausha.co/yEXw1UR2qKmV.mp3?t=1619332909
                                            [length] => 81096723
                                            [type] => audio/mpeg
                                        )

                                )

                            [link] => https://podcast.ausha.co/anecdotes/18-j-ai-tout-plaque-du-jour-au-lendemain-pour-partir-seule-j-ai-torpille-ma-vie-camille-dubois-leipp-fondatrice-de
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
```

It doesnt parse/show any of the "itunes:something" tags. Is anyone would have an idea why it doesnt parse and what solution I could use.

**I tried this but got php fatal error**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($r);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz');

foreach($xml->xpath('//i:author') as $itunes) {
    $itunes->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz');
    var_export($itunes->xpath('//i:author'));
}

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\xampp\htdocs\anecdotes\wp-content\themes\anecdoteschild\template-home.php:88 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\anecdotes\wp-content\themes\anecdoteschild\template-home.php(88): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\anecdotes\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\anecdotes\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\anecdotes\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\anecdotes\wp-content\themes\anecdoteschild\template-home.php on line 88
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: I tried two of the answers, it didn't work so far. I updated my message and shared what I did, maybe I did something wrong ?

Comment: `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz');` – that is the URL where you are requesting the data from, it is _not_ one of the namespace URIs.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message carefully: on the first line, it says "String could not be parsed as XML"; then at the end of the second line, it shows you've run `SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')`.

So that error is coming from the line `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($r);` because `$r` doesn't contain anything.

You seem to have got confused between two things:

- The Uniform Resource Locator (URL) you're trying to fetch XML from, which is "https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz"
- The Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) used to identify the different namespace you're interested in *inside* that XML, which is "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"

Go back to the first version of the code for loading the XML, which was working correctly:

```php
$url = "https://feed.ausha.co/bVn6ghlkLaaz";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Then, either use XPath to get the elements you want:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('i', "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd");

foreach($xml->xpath('//i:author') as $author) {
    echo $author;
}
```

Or use `->children()` to go to the element you want explicitly, as explained in [Reference - How do I handle namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)

```
echo $xml->channel->children("http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd")->author;
```

Comment: Hi @IMSoP, thank you very much for you reply which is helping a lot. Indeed I'm confuse about the urls used to identity the different namespace and even with the documentation (I mean your link with the all explanation which is very great imo) that explain in theory how it works, I still didn't get how you found out "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd". 
I also have another question, for example for the tag <itunes:images href"link">. If I understood well, I should use the attributes method for this one specific ?

Comment: @LeDude At the top of the XML, you can see this: `xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"`. That means "from now on, the prefix 'itunes:' means the namespace 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'". So when you see a tag like `<itunes:author>`, you can look back at the `xmlns` attributes and find that namespace. And yes, attributes without any prefix have to be accessed like `->attributes()->href`.

Comment: Ok after some trying I can finnaly get the href of <image:itunes href"">, this how I did : ```$image = $xml->xpath('//i:image')[1]['href'];
```. After reading again, the URLs is inside the xml, in the beggining. Thank you again IMSoP !

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351134/10644804) I was able to loop through the itunes namespaced elements and add them so that they would be loaded via simplexml. Here is what I used:

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file( feed_url );
  
        // Loop through the items
        foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $item ) {

            // Grab all of the itunes children
            $itunes_children = $item->children( 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd' );

            // Loop through the itunes children elements and add to the item.
            foreach ( $itunes_children as $name => $value ) {
                $item->addChild( 'itunes_' . $name, htmlspecialchars( $value ) );
            }
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $xml );
        echo '</pre>';
```