# How to make a SOAP request using cURL in PHP (Drupal)

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have been trying to get a SOAP request to work within a custom module for Drupal 7. I am using cURL to make the request within a function. At the moment the page I am using says it us under site maintenance whenever I activate the function. Below is an extract of a function. My question is how I can get the value of the email provided by the SOAP response and place it in a PHP variable? Below is my option for using SimpleXML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$namespace = 'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI';
$soap = $xml->children($namespace);
$subscriber_email = $soap->Body->RetrieveResponseMsg->Results->Properties->Property[2]->Value;
```

This is the result for SOAP request on its own using SOAP UI that I am trying to parse:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>[REMOVED]</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>[REMOVED]</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-715a4a7e-4657-48c7-8b01-612580d331ce">
            <wsu:Created>2019-03-04T12:41:08Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2019-03-04T12:46:08Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>[REMOVED]</RequestID>
         <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
            <Properties>
               <Property>
                  <Name>SubscriberID</Name>
                  <Value>[REMOVED]</Value>
               </Property>
               <Property>
                  <Name>FirstName</Name>
                  <Value>[REMOVED]</Value>
               </Property>
               <Property>
                  <Name>Email</Name>
                  <Value>[REMOVED]</Value>
               </Property>
            </Properties>
         </Results>
      </RetrieveResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! First of all, what is your question? There's just a statement what your page does, but nothing more. Second try to create a [mcve] as nobody will afford 15 min of understanding your code and analyzing your problem. Then [edit] your question - for more help take a look at [ask].

Comment: I have removed aspects of the function and clarified my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what `XML2Array::createArray` does, but my guess is that it's not what you want - generic function to flatten XML into an array rarely cover all cases. Try using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si or use [PHP's built-in SOAPClient](http://php.net/SoapClient).

Comment: @IMSoP I have tried SimpleXML option using the following code to try and access the email in the SOAP response: $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    $namespace = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
    $soap = $xml->children($namespace['soap']);
    $$subscriber_email = $soap->Body->RetrieveResponseMsg->Results->Properties->Property[2]->Value; . It still returned an error.

Comment: @Adutwum If you have additional code to show, the best idea is to [edit] it into your question. Comments aren't really designed to have lots of code and formatting. You can also simplify your question by ignoring the request part, and just showing us the XML response you're trying to parse (`$content`). We can't test the request anyway, so it doesn't contribute to a [mcve].

Comment: Your example code has a typo: `$$subscriber_email` instead of `$subscriber_email`. Also, check the question I linked: you don't need to call `$xml->getNamespaces(true)`, but you *do* need to call `->children()` again to change to the `http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI` namespace.