# How to use foreach with PHP & XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is my php code

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_string($ops_response);

foreach($xmldata->world-patent-data->biblio-search->search-result->exchange-documents->exchange-document->bibliographic-data->parties as $item)
{
echo "<p>Applicant Name: " . $item->applicants->applicant->applicant-name->name . "</p>";
echo "<p>Doc Number: " . $item->applicants->applicant->applicant-name->doc-number . "</p>";
echo "<p>Description: " . $item->applicants->applicant->applicant-name->abstract . "</p>";
}
```

This is my XML File:

```
https://ipappatent.com/xml/document.xml
```

Expected Result

```
 <p>Applicant Name: PHYLION BATTERY CO LTD</p>
 <p>Doc Number: 2018101613</p>
 <p>Description: A frame tube having a battery enclosure structure for an electric bike. The frame tube comprises a main body</p>


 <p>Year: ASTRO ENGINEERING CO LTD [TW]</p>
 <p>Category: 20180821</p>
 <p>Country: A drive assemblage is described for a vehicle drivable by muscle energy and/or—in particular additionally—by motor energy</p>
```

Iam new to PHP and i am not very well sure on how to handle the xml output? If anyone can help me on this pls do that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Add your `$xmldata` Result into your question.

Comment: Thats a huge resultset. The output is xml format. so i have uloaded that file https://ipappatent.com/xml/document.xml

Comment: The file is showing now. Can you pls check. Thx

Comment: Ca u try this link: http://ipappatent.com/xml/document.xml

Comment: It has a huge and confusing data Am very new with xml. Basically i want to get the Doc Number, Applicant Name, DEscription etc from the result set

Comment: I get the xml data from epo.org API. Its basically a patent search API.

Comment: i get the xml data as a response to the request. I get the data inline. To show it to you i creaated as an xml document and uploaded.

Comment: You had a chance to look at the xml document?

Comment: yes, I can see now

Comment: I wanna know if the for loop is correct? Getting a error " Undefined index: world-patent-data"

Comment: $xmldata comes in object or array ??

Comment: it comes as an array

Comment: See my answer foreach. This should works for array.

Comment: Yeah still getting the same error "Undefined index: ops:world-patent-data" in the foreach loop. Is the var which i am using  ops:world-patent-data correct as per the xml response?

Comment: You need to replace your xml response with `$ops_response = str_replace("ops:", "", $ops_response);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199717/discussion-between-vaibhavi-sojitra-and-sanju-menon).

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is very hard to answer without a [mcve](/help/mcve) - rather than trying to talk us through a whole XML document, you need to slice it up and try to get that working. However, do check existing questions and tips on using SimpleXML. Common problems are that names with hyphens in need to be written like `->('some-name'}` rather than `->some-name`; and names with colons in need to be [handled using namespace functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do like this. You have passes object instead of array.
Json decode and encode `simplexml_load_string($ops_response)`.

```
$string = //"your xml string here";

    echo "<pre>";
            $json = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($string)), 1);

    print_r($json);
    $json = $json['biblio-search']['search-result']['exchange-documents'];
    foreach($json as $item)
                {
                echo "<p>Applicant Name: " . $item['exchange-document']['bibliographic-data']['parties']['applicants']['applicant'][0]['applicant-name']['name'] . "</p>";

echo "<p>Description: " . $item['exchange-document']['abstract']['@attributes']['lang'] . "</p>";
               }
```

Comment: Please, please, do not do this. You will throw away parts of the XML, and throw away all the functionality of SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$myXMLData =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
  <user>John Doe</wronguser>
  <email>john@example.com</wrongemail>
</document>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} else {
    print_r($xml);
}
?>
```

hi try like this

Comment: I will check that Salim. Thank you