# Get Attribute value from Soap Response PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am getting a soap response as expected and then converting to an array. Here is my code:

```
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//soapBody')[0];
$array = json_decode( str_replace('@', '', json_encode((array)$body)), TRUE); 
print_r($array);
```

here is the output:

```
Array ( 
[GetCompanyCodeResponse] => Array ( 
    [GetCompanyCodeResult] => Array ( 
        [Customers] => Array ( 
            [Customer] => Array ( 
                [attributes] => Array ( 
                    [CustomerNo] => 103987 
                    [CustomerName] => epds api testers Inc 
                    [ContactId] => 219196 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

How do i echo the ContactId? Ive tried the following:

```
$att = $array->attributes();
$array->attributes()->{'ContactId'};
print_r($array);
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on array
```

Also tried:

```
$array->Customer['CustomerId'];
```

I get following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'Customer' of non-object
```

Expecting to get 219196

Comment: Try this:
```$array['GetCompanyCodeResponse']['GetCompanyCodeResult']['Customers']['attributes']['ContactId']```

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz Thats exactly what I came up with as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the above problem. Not sure if it is the most elegant way to do it, but it returns result as expected. If there is a more efficient way to get the ContactId, I am open to suggestions.

```
print_r($array['GetCompanyCodeResponse']['GetCompanyCodeResult']
['Customers']['Customer']['attributes']['ContactId']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have followed some very bad advice on how to parse the XML, and completely thrown away the functionality of SimpleXML.

Specifically, the reason you can't run the `attributes()` method is that you've converted the SimpleXML object to a plain array using this ugly hack:

```
$array = json_decode( str_replace('@', '', json_encode((array)$body)), TRUE);
```

To use SimpleXML as its authors intended, I suggest you read:

- [The examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)
- [This reference answer on handling XML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si/)

Since you didn't paste the actual XML in the question, I'm going to take a guess that it looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body xmlns="http://www.example.org/companyInfo">
      <GetCompanyCodeResponse>
         <GetCompanyCodeResult>
            <Customers>
                <Customer CustomerNo="103987" CustomerName="epds api testers Inc" ContactId="219196" />
            </Customers>
         </GetCompanyCodeResult>
      </GetCompanyCodeResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If that is in `$response`, we don't need to do any weirdness with `str_replace` or `json_encode`, we can use the methods built into SimpleXML to navigate around the XML:

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
// The Body is in the SOAP Envelope namespace
$body = $xml->children('http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope')->Body;
// The element inside that is in some other namespace
$innerResponse = $body->children('http://www.example.org/companyInfo')->GetCompanyCodeResponse;
// We need to traverse the XML to get to the node we're interested in
$customer = $innerResponse->GetCompanyCodeResult->Customers->Customer;
// Unprefixed attributes aren't technically in any namespace (an oddity in the XML namespace spec!)
$attributes = $customer->attributes(null);
// Here's the value you were looking for
echo $attributes['ContactId'];
```

Unlike your previous code, this won't break if:

- The server starts using a different local prefix instead of `soap:`, or adding a prefix on the `GetCompanyCodeResponse` element
- The response comes back with more than one `Customer` (the `->Customer` always means the same as `->Customer[0]`, the first child element with that name)
- The `Customer` element has child elements or text content as well as attributes

It also allows you to use other features of SimpleXML, like [using an `xpath` expression to search the document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) or even [switching to the full DOM API for more complex operations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php).

Comment: I tried with simpleXML and received nothing but errors. If you notice, I said not sure if the answer was right/wrong..but it did indeed work. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @jasone So does this answer help you, or is there anything you still don't understand?