# Delete first line and process xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I have a timestamp in an xml file and i need to skip the timestamp which is present in first line and process xml file with PHP. Below is the example of my XML file.

```
2020-03-31T00:00:00-0500
<list>
    <listing>
        <ad_id>20624163</ad_id>
        <date_created>01-Apr-18</date_created>
        <price>$465,000</price>
     </listing>   
</list>  
<list>
    <listing>
        <ad_id>20624657</ad_id>
        <date_created>27-Apr-18</date_created>
        <price>$446,000</price>
     </listing>   
</list>
```

Below is the function which i am trying to process the XML file.

```
  function namespacedXMLToArray($xmlData) {
    return json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlData)), true);
  }
```

Is there anyway i can skip the timestamp in first line?

Comment: How do you get `$xmlData`?  Might be easier there.

Comment: Just as a side note, please check [the examples in the manual of how to use SimpleXML objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) rather than using the `json_decode(json_encode` hack to get an array. If you're having problems with namespaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si

Comment: The XML also should have a single root element, so is that the actual XML file or just a part of it?