# How to access the data in this XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

so I have a XML invoice and I want to access the data in it and I am absolutely clueless on how to do it. I tried following various guides online and nothing works, I get zero errors but zero results.

The XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dat:dataPack id="fa001" application="StwTest" version="2.0" note="Import" xmlns:dat="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd" xmlns:inv="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd" xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd">

<dat:dataPackItem id="20007" version="2.0">
    <inv:invoice version="2.0">
        <inv:invoiceHeader>
            <inv:invoiceType>issuedInvoice</inv:invoiceType>
            <inv:number>
              <typ:numberRequested>20007</typ:numberRequested>
            </inv:number>
            <inv:paymentType>
              <typ:paymentType>draft</typ:paymentType>
            </inv:paymentType>
            <inv:carrier>
            <typ:ids>magic horse</typ:ids>
            </inv:carrier>
            <inv:numberOrder>20007</inv:numberOrder>
            <inv:symVar>20007</inv:symVar>
            <inv:date>2020-05-11</inv:date>
            <inv:dateTax>2020-05-13</inv:dateTax>
            <inv:dateDue>2020-05-27</inv:dateDue>
        </inv:invoiceHeader>                
    </inv:invoice>
</dat:dataPackItem>

</dat:dataPack>
```

and for example I want to access the date 2020-05-11 so I tried this:

```
$payment_vat_xml = simplexml_load_file(filepath);
echo $payment_vat_xml->{'dat:dataPackItem'}->{'inv:invoice'}->{'inv:invoiceHeader'}->{'inv:date'};
```

but I get no result.

Any help will be much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Try using xpath `echo $payment_vat_xml->xpath('/dat:dataPack/dat:dataPackItem/inv:invoice/inv:invoiceHeader/inv:date')[0];`

Comment: This works, perfect, thank you! Would you spare a moment to explain why my attempt didn't work and how did you figure out this method should be used?

Comment: See this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Would you mind posting this as an answer to my question so that I can flag it as a correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use

```
echo $payment_vat_xml->xpath('/dat:dataPack/dat:dataPackItem/inv:invoice/inv:invoiceHeader/inv:date')[0];
```

Detailed explanation can be found here: [Reference - how do I handle namespaces (tags and attributes with colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)

Thanks [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)