# Trying to Prase XML using Simple_xml_load_string to get most inner data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having a mare of a week trying to get into some data pulled from a simple XML call. Having read many articles on here, and elsewhere, none have actually explained why I am unable make a simple XML into an Array, or JSON.  So, here is a portion of the XML:

```
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <aims_CostComparisonResponse
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <aims_CostComparisonResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns=""
                xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="ExpressOptions">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ComparisonName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="ServiceInformation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="ShippingCharge" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="TransitLow" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="TransitHigh" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram
                xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
                xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                <NewDataSet
                    xmlns="">
                    <ExpressOptions diffgr:id="ExpressOptions1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                        <ComparisonName>17:30</ComparisonName>
                        <ServiceInformation></ServiceInformation>
                        <ShippingCharge>0.00</ShippingCharge>
                        <TransitLow>1</TransitLow>
                        <TransitHigh>1</TransitHigh>
                    </ExpressOptions>
                </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
        </aims_CostComparisonResult>
    </aims_CostComparisonResponse>
</s:Body>
```

</s:Envelope>

Simply put, I am trying to get each node of the `ExpressOptions` which is under the `NewDataSet`.

I have tried multiple ways to convert the response, was is as raw as above, with no information at all coming back.  Unless I put `$xml->getName()` which gives me "Envolope".

The response comes in from the CURL call with this:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

I then tried to manually get to the bottom of understanding the layout of the given table:

```
echo($xml->Body->aims_CostComparisonResponse->aims_CostComparisonResult->{'diffgr:diffgram'}->NewDataSet[0]->ComparisonName);
```

The expectation was to get "UPS" or something, but just empty.  Reading the PHP Manual on Simple XML Load String, I tried the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$xmlArray = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

And

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$xmlArray = (array)$xml;
```

I seem unable to A) get any information directly out of it, even using `echo ($xml->Body->aims_CostComparisonResponse->aims_CostComparisonResult` something out. Also various ForEach using `$xml->children` to find a path.

I can echo the `$response` using `echo htmlentities($response)`. So I know the data is there, but it elludes me as to how to get the information out.  Please any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - how do I handle namespaces (tags and attributes with colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)

Comment: The sample xml in your question is not well formed; can you edit and fix it? It will be easier to answer a question with a valid xml. And while you are at it, can you also show the exact output expected from the sample xml?

Comment: @JackFleeting Hello, I actually used an online XML formatter as when I copy the data from the browser after a call, it is just in one clump.  Can you suggest a better online formatter if the one I selected, which was first in Google Search.  I can then re-paste the data no problem.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for the link. I honestly do not know if that answers my question because I am not aware the colon mattered until now.  The assumption being that because of the `<s:Body>` for example, I cannot get too the main body of the data.  I will have a play and see. and will come back to this.

Comment: As an extra tip, if you see anyone recommending running `json_encode` and `json_decode` on your SimpleXML objects, ignore them. All that does is throw away all the SimpleXML functionality, and with it probably a bunch of data.

Comment: @IMSoP I cannot get that other post to work in this situ.  Am I correct, if I can get to A name space, and use` getNamespaces()` I should get others below it, or within its tags?

Comment: @AndrewWalker You don't need to call `getNamespaces`, just look at the XML, specifically the `xmlns` attributes. I've added an answer addressing this specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're struggling is because this XML contains multiple namespaces, as discussed in this question: [Reference - how do I handle namespaces (tags and attributes with colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)

To get to the element you want, you need to go through these namespaces (just look for the `xmlns` attributes):

- `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` (with the local prefix `s:`) for `Body` (your `$xml` variable will point at `Envelope`, but you still need to select the namespace)
- `"http://tempuri.org/"` for `aims_CostComparisonResponse` and `aims_CostComparisonResult`
- `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"` (with the local prefix `diffgr:`) for `diffgram`
- `""` for `NewDataSet`, `ExpressOptions` (which you missed out in your code), and `ComparisonName`

So the final chain looks like this:

```php
echo $xml->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")->Body
         ->children("http://tempuri.org/")->aims_CostComparisonResponse->aims_CostComparisonResult
         ->children("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1")->diffgram
         ->children("")->NewDataSet->ExpressOptions->ComparisonName;
```

Comment: Thank you, so my misunderstanding was the word NameSpace, I thought the name space was the name, and the attribute had the link.  So the namespaces I trying to grab was `s`, `xs`, `differ`, rather than the links.  Seems a very messy way to display data.  If any of those links change by the author of the data, my system is is vulnerable, correct ?

Comment: @AndrewWalker No, you don't actually have to follow the links, and most of the time there won't be anything useful there if you do.The only reason they're URIs rather than any other string is so that everyone can choose names that they "own", and don't have to worry about picking one that somebody else owns. Of course, people then use them really badly, and you get nonsense like `http://tempuri.org/` which is supposed to be a placeholder meaning "temporary URI", but people leave in their production code.