# How to parse an image tag in xml sitemap?

Tags: php, xml, image, parsing

```
<url>
<loc>
<![CDATA[ https://www.news18.com/photogallery/photogallery/in-photos-five-most-expensive-face-masks-for-protection-from-covid-19-in-the-world-3519821.html ]]>
</loc>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
<![CDATA[ https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/03/1615377235_mask-1.jpg ]]>
</image:loc>
<image:caption>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</image:caption>
</image:image>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
<![CDATA[ https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/03/1615377250_mask-2.jpg ]]>
</image:loc>
<image:caption>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</image:caption>
</image:image>
</url>
```

How can I Select image:image element in php if i write $xml->url->image:image  |  It Will be Wrong Syntax

Comment: I need this Now!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a good idea to familiarize yourself with [XML Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894427/231316) first.

I'm going to assume that at a higher level you have something that is explaining what `image:` represents. If you don't, that's a different problem and you arguably don't have XML, just something that looks a lot like it. Here's you exact same XML but wrapped in what I assume is an [Image Sitemap as defined by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/image-sitemaps).

```php
$xml = <<<'TAG'
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
<loc>
<![CDATA[ https://www.news18.com/photogallery/photogallery/in-photos-five-most-expensive-face-masks-for-protection-from-covid-19-in-the-world-3519821.html ]]>
</loc>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
<![CDATA[ https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/03/1615377235_mask-1.jpg ]]>
</image:loc>
<image:caption>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</image:caption>
</image:image>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
<![CDATA[ https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/03/1615377250_mask-2.jpg ]]>
</image:loc>
<image:caption>
<![CDATA[ ]]>
</image:caption>
</image:image>
</url>
</urlset>
TAG;
```

To access things by a namespace, you call `children()` on the node with the appropriate namespace expansion:

```php
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $doc->url[0]->children('http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1')->image->loc;
```

This prints out:

```
 https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/03/1615377235_mask-1.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, This Worked Well!