# Parsing news:news in urlset of a sitemap

Tags: php, laravel, sitemap

When I try to parse sitemap data and I can get loc field.

```
$sitemapContent = simplexml_load_file($publisher['url']);

foreach ($sitemapContent as $sitemapItem) {
    dd($sitemapItem->loc); // Ouputs SitemapXMLElement containing loc and lastmod
}
```

...but in the sitemap there are more fields like this:

...
news:news
news:publication
news:nameAcme</news:name>

Is there a way to access the publication name via $sitemapItem?

Comment: You need to reference the namespace specifically. There's a couple of ways, here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66569256/231316

Comment: You can not dump completely simpleXml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Chris Haas's comment, I found a solution:

```
$newsNamespace = $sitemapItem->children('http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9');
```

This way I can access news namespace.