# Getting the correct data from an XML file for a SoapClient request

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

To have a point of reference, let's use this public WSDL: https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?WSDL

Now this thing should accept the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <NumberToWords xmlns="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
      <ubiNum>500</ubiNum>
    </NumberToWords>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is the code:

```
$requestData = simplexml_load_file($file); 
//enabling or disabling the following line does not seem to make a difference, but I used it at some point to see that it does load something in there
$requestData->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
//print_r($requestData->xpath('//soap:Body')); //I was using this to check that the data is actually there, and it is...

$webService = new SoapClient($url);
$result = $webService->NumberToWords($requestData);

print_r($result)
```

And I'm getting this beautiful response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [NumberToWordsResult] => zero
)
```

I think it has something to do with how simpleXML load the data in, but I had no luck figuring out what I should do.

As a side note, if I try just manually setting the data:

```
$requestData = ["ubiNum"=>500];
```

it works, but I really want to figure out what is going on with the xml parsing/sending

Also if interested, my commented out `print_r`'s result is the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [NumberToWords] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [ubiNum] => 500
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: So far the best solution I found is to get the xml in an `stdClass` by parsing the string, and : `json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string(strtr($xml, ['</soap:' => '</', '<soap:' => '<']))))`... Is there nothing more elegant to parse simplexml?

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to edit or at least access the `ubiNum` from the loaded file, shouldn't `$requestData = simplexml_load_file($file); echo $requestData->{'soap:Body'}->NumberToWords->ubiNum->nodeValue;` return `500`? I'm getting "property of non-object"

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting old or if I'm just stupid, but I really don't get it. Calling children with a prefix, should be the same as using a key with the prefix, no? So if there is a prefix, I must do something like this: `$requestData->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")->children("http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver")->children("http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver")->nodeValue`? (PS: I understand that empty namespace do not need a namespace, I just want to grasp how different levels would be accessed)

Comment: Ok, so this returns the number: `$requestData->children("soap",true)->children()->NumberToWords->ubiNum` but what I do not get is why? The first `children(...)` returns the soap:Body, so shouldn't the second `children()` return the NumberToWords? Why do I need to access that with another definition?

Comment: It is a little confusing, but it might help to notice that "children" is plural there: the first call to `->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')` doesn't give you the Body element specifically, it gives you all the children at that level, the just happens to only be one. So to reference the Body, you name it: `->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body`. Then your can ask for the children of that, and so on.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with what I think would be the correct code to access that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SoapClient, you don't need to also construct the whole XML yourself. Depending on the service, you either need to pass style individual variables, or the contents of the "body".

As you say, you can just run:

```php
$webService = new SoapClient($url);
$result = $webService->NumberToWords(["ubiNum"=>500]);
```

Underneath, the SoapClient class is generating the rest of the XML for you and sending it as an HTTP request.

If you want to get the data to send out of an XML document, you need to extract just that part, rather than trying to send the whole SOAP envelope inside the parameter. In this example, you need to navigate to the "NumberToWords" element; see [this reference question for tips on navigating the XML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957) but in this example you'd use something like this:

```php
$requestData = simplexml_load_file($file);
$soapBody = $requestData->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body;
$numberToWords = $soapBody->children('http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/')->NumberToWords;
// Or to get the 500 directly:
$ubiNum = (int)$numberToWords->ubiNum;
```

Alternatively, you can just ignore the SoapClient class, construct the XML yourself, and post it with an HTTP client like Guzzle. Often the only extra step you'll need is to set the correct "SOAPAction" HTTP header.

Comment: As I said, I do realize that I can construct the body manually from an array, but I have ready xml files with the requests I will need so it will be **very** useful if I could just parse those, alter them (when/if needed) and push them. Maybe I should rephrase the question to be more about parsing the xml?

Comment: If you have the requests built already, including the SOAP envelope etc, just use an HTTP client. The whole point of using a dedicated SOAP client is to build that XML for you.

Comment: It's way more complicated than that. I need a mixture of both, mostly for DEV tests...