# Are SimpleXMLElement and SimpleXMLElement::children() the same thing?

Tags: php, simplexml

Consider the following code:

```
<?php
$foo = new SimpleXmlElement(
'<foo>
    <bar>
        <baz id="b1"/>
        <baz id="b2"/>
        <baz id="b3"/>
    </bar>
</foo>
');
echo "<pre>";print_r($foo);echo "</pre><br/>";
echo "<pre>";print_r($foo->children());echo "</pre><br/>";
echo "foo===foo->children():".($foo===$foo->children()?"true":"false")."<br/>";//false
echo "foo==foo->children():".($foo==$foo->children()?"true":"false");//true
```

print_r shows the same content for foo and foo->children(). $foo==$foo->children() is true but $foo===$foo->children() is false. What the heck is $foo->children()?

The [official document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) has a note that may be related to this question, but I cannot understand exactly its meaning.

> Note: SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most
> methods. They cannot be viewed using var_dump() or anything else which
> can examine objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its name, instances of the `SimpleXMLElement` class can represent a few different things:

- A single XML element; in your example, `$foo` represents the `<foo>` element at the root of your XML document
- A collection of XML elements with the same name; for instance, `$foo->bar` gives you an object with all child elements named `bar`
- A collection of XML elements with *different* names, but the same parent; this is what `->children()` gives you
- A single XML *attribute*; `$foo->bar[0]->baz[0]['id']` will give you an object for the `id` attribute of the first `baz` in your example
- A collection of XML attributes on the same element; this is what `->attributes()` gives you

A lot of the time, you don't actually notice which of these you have, because various short-hands let you treat them interchangeably; for instance:

- Property, method, and attribute calls on collections of elements and attributes generally refer to the first element in the collection. So `$foo->bar->baz['id']` is the same as `$foo->bar[0]->baz[0]['id']`
- Conversely, using a `foreach` loop with an object representing a single node automatically loops over the children of that element, as though you'd called `->children()`

There are however times when you need to tell the difference. For instance, `foreach ( $foo->bar as $item )` will loop over all elements named `bar`; but `foreach ( $foo->bar->children() as $item )` will access the *first* element named `bar`, and loop over *its* children.

The `children()` method is also used to switch between namespaces, see [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957)

Answer (score 1):

As the name indicates **SimpleXMLElement::children** is a member function is simply returns the children elements as objects from SimpleXMLElement class object.
It always return a 'SimpleXMLElement' class object unless the node represents an attribute (id, class etc can be consider as attributes), in which case null is returned.

Consider this example

```
$foo = new SimpleXmlElement(
'<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz id="b1">b1</baz>
    <baz id="b2">b2</baz>
    <baz id="b3">b3</baz>
    <pas id="p1">p1</pas>
  </bar>
 </foo>');
$mainfoo = json_encode($foo); var_dump($mainfoo); // string(50) "{"bar":{"baz":["b1","b2","b3"],"pas":["p1","p2"]}}"
$children = json_encode($foo->children()); var_dump($children ); // string(50) "{"bar":{"baz":["b1","b2","b3"],"pas":["p1","p2"]}}"
$childrenofbar = json_encode($foo->bar->children()); var_dump($childrenofbar ); //string(42) "{"baz":["b1","b2","b3"],"pas":["p1","p2"]}"
$children_bar_pas = json_encode($foo->bar->pas); var_dump($children_bar_pas); //string(45) "{"@attributes":{"id":"p1"},"0":"p1","1":"p2"}"
```

We can not use var_dump to view and verify SimpleXmlElement object. So for convenient manner , we can simply json_encode them and var_dump them ;)

Here the first statement converts an xml/markup string to SimpleXmlElement class object.

$foo->children() brings the children elements as a SimpleXmlElement class objects

$foo->bar->children() brings the children elements of 'bar'.

As per the documentation, object of a SimpleXmlElement is iterable using php loops such as for/ foreach etc..

```
foreach($foo as $f1) {
  var_dump(json_encode($f1)); // "{"baz":["b1","b2","b3"],"pas":["p1","p2"]}"
}

foreach($foo->children() as $f2) {
  var_dump(json_encode($f2)); // string(42) "{"baz":["b1","b2","b3"],"pas":["p1","p2"]}"
}
```

children() method can also use to access child elements for the markups having valid namespace. Please see the Example #2 in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)!

Comment: Rather than viewing the object as JSON, it makes more sense to view it as _XML_, with the `->asXML()` method. Like `print_r`, `json_encode` will hide information in some cases.