# PHP - xml parsing - multiple subelements

Tags: php, xml, parsing

**What I am trying to achieve:**

A php method (function) to return all the subelements of an XML element.

**the XML file** *(excerpt of the relevant part)*

```
<D:CIN>
 <D:PP>
  <D:T>
  subelement value 1
  </D:T>
  <D:T>
  subelement value 2
  </D:T>
  <D:T>
  subelement value 3
  </D:T>
 </D:PP>
</D:CIN>
```

My php code (excerpt of the relevant part):

```
class Feeder
{
...
    private function parse_xml($xml)
{
    $parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); 
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); 
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $values);
    xml_parser_free($parser);
   
    $return = array(); // The returned array
    $stack = array(); // tmp array used for stacking
    foreach($values as $val) {
      if($val['type'] == "open") {
        array_push($stack, $val['tag']);
      } elseif($val['type'] == "close") {
        array_pop($stack);
      } elseif($val['type'] == "complete") {
        array_push($stack, $val['tag']);
        $this->setArrayValue($return, $stack, $val['value']);
        array_pop($stack);
      }//if-elseif
    }//foreach
    return $return;
  }

  ...

 $this->dom = new DOMDocument;
 $this->dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;

 $this->dom->loadXML($this->resp);
 $this->dom->save($this->save_path);
 $this->read_xml($this->save_path);
 $fp = fopen($path,"r");
 $this->xml = fread($fp, 4096); 
 $array = $this->parse_xml($this->xml);
        
$this->data = $array[root element and relevant child elements included here]['D:CIN']['D:PP'];

...
}
```

Calling and printing the content of the object property *$data* by:

```
$test = new Feeder();
print_r($test->data);
```

returns an array containing just the last <D:T> subelement (not all three <D:T> subelements contained in the XML):

> Array ( [D:T] => subelement value 3 )

**Question:**
How can I please get all of the <D:T> subelements (not just the last one).

Many thanks

Comment: Most of the relevant code is in `$array = $this->parse_xml($this->xml);` which you haven't shown us. Personally, I would use SimpleXML rather than DOM, and not bother with an intermediate array - noting that you'll need to interact with namespaces as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957

Comment: @IMSoP Many thanks for pointing this out. Please see the EDIT above.

Comment: Thanks, but now we need to see `setArrayValue`; try to make a [mre] - a self-contained version of your code that we could actually run with the input given and see the same results as you, rather than fragments of the real application.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you're not really using DOM to do your parsing, I would strongly recommend using SimpleXML instead of building your own parse function.

You will need to [understand what XML Namespaces are and how to work with them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957), but this will make your code more resilient in the long-term because the author of the XML might switch to a different prefix instead of "D:", which would break your current code.

Assuming the full XML looks something like this:

```xml
<A:EXAMPLE xmlns:A="urn:example:alpha" xmlns:D="urn:example:delta">
<D:CIN>
 <D:PP>
  <D:T>
  subelement value 1
  </D:T>
  <D:T>
  subelement value 2
  </D:T>
  <D:T>
  subelement value 3
  </D:T>
 </D:PP>
</D:CIN>
</A:EXAMPLE>
```

Then your code could look like this:

```php
$sx = simplexml_load_file($path);
$cin = $sx->children('urn:example:delta')->CIN;
foreach ( $cin->PP->T as $subelement ) {
    $subelement_value = (string)$subelement;
    $subelement_value = trim($subelement_value);
    // do whatever you need with $subelement_value
}
```

Here is a [live demo of that example](https://3v4l.org/fmeGY).

Comment: Many thanks. That solved it. I also was not aware about the potential problem with the potential future change of prefix.