# PHP - simpleXML namespaces with different prefices

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

**What I am trying to achieve:**

To get the values of all `<D:T>` elements in the following [XML](https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_or.cgi?ico=45801576)

All the articles dealing with this question (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei), that was otherwise extremely helpful to understand how namespaces work) only address the situation when there is a single namespaced element.

What I am struggling with and cannot really find an answer to anywhere is how do I access the `<D:T>` elements when there is an extra element: `<are:Odpoved>` with a different prefix following the root element (as is the case in the [XML](https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_or.cgi?ico=45801576) referred to above).

**What I tried:**

I defined the prefices:

```php
define('are','http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_or/v_1.0.3');
define('dtype', 'http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_datatypes/v_1.0.3');
```

and then tried:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
    $sx = simplexml_load_file($path);
    $cin = $sx->children(are)->Ares_odpovedi->Odpoved->children(dtype)->CIN;
    
    foreach ( $cin->PP->T as $subelement ) 
    {
        $subelement_value = (string)$subelement;
        $subelement_value = trim($subelement_value);
    }
```

This returns: ***Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function children() on null*

I tried different options, but none of them work.

Comment: Can you post the XML, including the namespace definitions etc?

Comment: Hey, it is available under the "XML" link in the first sentence of my post. Please let me know if it does not work or if I should make it available otherwise.

Comment: OK. sorry, missed that

Comment: In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338382/php-xml-parsing-multiple-subelements) you were using `DOMDocument` and other techniques. If you are open to using `DOMDocument` rather than `SimpleXML` then I can suggest how you can do this

Comment: Looks like the structure is different to what you seem to think - `$cin = $sx->children(are)->Odpoved->children(dtype)->Vypis_OR->CIN->PP->T;`. and then `foreach ( $cin as ...`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thank you for your answer. Originally I was using `DOMDocument`, but I have been trying to use `SimpleXML`, as it was pointed to me in that question that using `DOMDocument` is not ideal in my case (due to the fact that my script may cease to work if the author of the XML (API owner) changes the prefix.

Comment: @NigelRen You are absolutely right, there was an additional element `Vypis_OR`. I added it into the syntax as you proposed and everything works. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got what you needed here, but for future questions please don't rely on external links for vital parts of the question. Try to simplify the example so that you can include it directly in the question.