# i can't read and parse xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have a xml file and I am trying to access the data in a xml file but it return an empty array.

i have a xml file and I am trying to access the data in a xml file but it return an empty array.

Could the problem be in the file itself?

I have tried to use Basic SimpleXML usage
this is my php code i used:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$xml = file_get_contents("https://egytech4uu.herokuapp.com/data.xml");

$XML = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($XML);
$arr = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($arr);

?>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Prices_Feed/Service1">
  <xs:schema id="Ticker" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="Ticker" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Time">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TIME" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Ticker">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SYMBOL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ARABIC_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="CLOSE" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="OPEN" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ENGLISH_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <Ticker xmlns="">
      <Time diffgr:id="Time1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <TIME>2022-03-28T14:29:56+02:00</TIME>
      </Time>
      <Ticker diffgr:id="Ticker1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <SYMBOL>OFH.CA</SYMBOL>
        <ARABIC_NAME>اوراسكوم المالية القابضة</ARABIC_NAME>
        <CLOSE>0.1820</CLOSE>
        <OPEN>0.19</OPEN>
        <ENGLISH_NAME>Orascom Financial Holding</ENGLISH_NAME>
      </Ticker>
      <Ticker diffgr:id="Ticker2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <SYMBOL>AMOC.CA</SYMBOL>
        <ARABIC_NAME>الاسكندرية للزيوت المعدنية</ARABIC_NAME>
        <CLOSE>4.08</CLOSE>
        <OPEN>4.33</OPEN>
        <ENGLISH_NAME>Alexandria Mineral Oils Company</ENGLISH_NAME>
      </Ticker>
      <Ticker diffgr:id="Ticker3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <SYMBOL>OIH.CA</SYMBOL>
        <ARABIC_NAME>اوراسكوم للاستثمار القابضة</ARABIC_NAME>
        <CLOSE>0.2250</CLOSE>
        <OPEN>0.2280</OPEN>
        <ENGLISH_NAME>Orascom Investment Holding</ENGLISH_NAME>
      </Ticker>
      <Ticker diffgr:id="Ticker4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
        <SYMBOL>EDBM.CA</SYMBOL>
        <ARABIC_NAME>المصرية لتطوير صناعة البناء (ليفت سلاب مصر )</ARABIC_NAME>
        <CLOSE>0.2690</CLOSE>
        <OPEN>0.2780</OPEN>
        <ENGLISH_NAME>Egyptian for Developing Building Materials</ENGLISH_NAME>
      </Ticker>
      <Ticker diffgr:id="Ticker5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
        <SYMBOL>MTIE.CA</SYMBOL>
        <ARABIC_NAME>ام.ام جروب للصناعة والتجارة العالمية</ARABIC_NAME>
        <CLOSE>4.13</CLOSE>
        <OPEN>4.46</OPEN>
        <ENGLISH_NAME>MM Group For Industry And International Trade</ENGLISH_NAME>
      </Ticker>
      <Ticker diffgr:id="Ticker6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
        <SYMBOL>UNIP.CA</SYMBOL>
        <ARABIC_NAME>يونيفرسال لصناعة مواد التعبئة و التغليف و الورق - يونيباك</ARABIC_NAME>
        <CLOSE>0.4280</CLOSE>
        <OPEN>0.4210</OPEN>
        <ENGLISH_NAME>Universal For Paper and Packaging Materials (Unipack</ENGLISH_NAME>
      </Ticker>
    </Ticker>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to turn it into JSON? Just use `var_dump($XML)`

Comment: @Barmar i need to parse this xml file and get <Ticker xmlns=""> data into and array to save it in database

Comment: Then use the simple XML API to search for the elements that you want. Converting it to JSON won't help with what you want to do.

Comment: @Barmar They're not actually trying to get JSON. For some reason, people always think they need to turn SimpleXML objects into arrays before they work with them. Somebody discovered a weird hack where converting to JSON and back again gives you an array, and now everybody copies and pastes that around, thinking it's how you're supposed to use this API. The same goes for LIBXML_NOCDATA - it's essentially useless in this context, but somebody once found that it makes the result of print_r slightly better, so now everyone thinks it's a magic word you have to use every time.

Comment: @Barmar Also, var_dump is actually *not* a great tool to use in this case, because the object has a lot of internal state and magic accessors which don't show up with standard functions like that.

Comment: @IMSoP True. But presumably the ultimate objective isn't to print the data, but to extract values from it. Neither method solve that.

Comment: @IMSoP I've already tried using an example from php.net/simplexml and it ony return SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) , i tried another xml file and it works fine . Could the problem be in the file itself?

Comment: As I say, show us a sample of the XML, and what you tried. Probably there's a specific structure in the file that you need to account for when accessing it, but I'm not going to confuse you further by guessing, and I'm not going to download a file from some dodgy looking URL to find out.

Comment: @IMSoP this is a sample of the xml https://egytech4uu.herokuapp.com/data.xml    I already put it in the code above , it's a 1506 lines i can't put it in the comment

Comment: @IMSoP I have reduced the number of items in the xml file now and i have modified the post. You can see the content of the file now

Comment: Great. So now I can see that the structure you need to understand is **namespaces**, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei Just remember: you do not need to convert it to an array, and print_r doesn't always show you everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one for you:

```
<?php
$xmldata = file_get_contents("https://egytech4uu.herokuapp.com/data.xml");
$xmlparser = xml_parser_create();
$arr = [];
xml_parse_into_struct($xmlparser, $xmldata, $arr);
xml_parser_free($xmlparser);
print_r($arr);
```

So what's going there? It returns a **flat** array, but for each node at least we can see its level. As mentioned in the comments, this is not the best way to parse XML, only a last resort kind of thing.

Comment: it works thx + could you help me to loop Ticker data in foreach loop , i don't know how to access the Ticker in the xml

Comment: This is a really horrible way of working with XML. SimpleXML does all the hard work for you, the data is all there, you just need to spend a few minutes learning how to access it.

Comment: I agree I will shorten my answer

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about SimpleXML is that it doesn't create objects *containing* the XML it's parsed, it just gives an API for *accessing data inside* that XML. So to work with it, you need to understand the structure of the XML, and decide what data you want to get out of it.

In this case, the `xmlns` attributes represent **XML namespaces**, so you need to understand how to work with those, which is discussed in detail here: [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957).

You haven't actually said what data you want to get out, so I'll use as an example getting the SYMBOLS from the inner list of Ticker elements. To get to those, you need to traverse through:

- The `<diffgr:diffgram>` element, which is in namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1` as indicated by its `xmlns:diffgr` attribute
- The outer `<Ticker>` element, which is in a namespace with an empty URI (`xmlns=""`)
- The inner `<Ticker>` elements, which we want to loop over
- The `<SYMBOL>` element in each one, which we want to extract the string content of

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml); // Note: no additional options needed here

// Switch to the namespace given by xmlns:diffgr=""...", and select the "diffgram" element
$diffgram = $sx->children('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1')->diffgram;
// Switch to the namespace with an empty URI, because the elements have xmlns=""
$emptyNamespaceChildren = $diffgram->children("");

// Select the outer Ticker element
$outerTicker = $emptyNamespaceChildren->Ticker;

// Loop over the inner Ticker elements
$symbols = [];
foreach ( $outerTicker->Ticker as $ticker ) {
    // Get some data out, in this case the SYMBOL of each Ticker
    // Using (string) gives us the content of the element, rather than an object
    $symbols[] = (string)$ticker->SYMBOL;
}
```

Note that all the extra variables here are just for readability, and in practice you might not write it so verbosely. At the other extreme, you could put it all on one line, going through all the levels until you get to the part where you want to loop, like this:

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$symbols = [];
foreach ( $sx->children('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1')->diffgram->children("")->Ticker->Ticker as $ticker ) {
    $symbols[] = (string)$ticker->SYMBOL;
}
```