# How do I access XML Data

Tags: php, soap, guzzle

I am using PHP to connect to a SOAP API using GuzzleHttp.

Code

```
$client = new Client();
$headers = [
    'Host' => 'server',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction' => 'action'
];
$body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetInventoryStatus xmlns="action">
      <Credentials>
        <Username></Username>
        <Password></Password>
      </Credentials>
      <MaterialCode>' . $_GET['matcode'] . '</MaterialCode>
    </GetInventoryStatus>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';
$request = new Request('POST', 'web service here', $headers, $body);
$res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
$xml1 = ($res->getBody());
```

After running the API, I get the result back in text but upon viewing the source code the below XML is getting returned back

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetInventoryStatusResponse
            xmlns="http://localhost/EnterpriseWebService/Enterprise Connect">
            <GetInventoryStatusResult>
                <MaterialCode>10029</MaterialCode>
                <MaterialDescription>12 PT TANGO C2S</MaterialDescription>
                <QuantityOnHand>138000.00</QuantityOnHand>
                <QuantityAllocated>20400.00</QuantityAllocated>
                <QuantityAvailable>117600.00</QuantityAvailable>
                <QuantityOnOrder>0.00</QuantityOnOrder>
                <QuantityInProduction>0.00</QuantityInProduction>
                <ReorderQuantity>0.00</ReorderQuantity>
                <ReorderLevel>0.00</ReorderLevel>
                <DesiredLevel>0.00</DesiredLevel>
            </GetInventoryStatusResult>
        </GetInventoryStatusResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I echo the `$xml1`, I get everything in text format.

How do I access the variables through the XML?

Comment: `namespace error : xmlns: 'http://localhost/EnterpriseWebService/Enterprise Connect' is not a valid URI`

Comment: This reference might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it. I have used `DOMDocument` but one could use other techniques.

```php
<?php
$str = '<' . '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetInventoryStatusResponse
            xmlns="http://localhost/EnterpriseWebService/EnterpriseConnect">
            <GetInventoryStatusResult>
                <MaterialCode>10029</MaterialCode>
                <MaterialDescription>12 PT TANGO C2S</MaterialDescription>
                <QuantityOnHand>138000.00</QuantityOnHand>
                <QuantityAllocated>20400.00</QuantityAllocated>
                <QuantityAvailable>117600.00</QuantityAvailable>
                <QuantityOnOrder>0.00</QuantityOnOrder>
                <QuantityInProduction>0.00</QuantityInProduction>
                <ReorderQuantity>0.00</ReorderQuantity>
                <ReorderLevel>0.00</ReorderLevel>
                <DesiredLevel>0.00</DesiredLevel>
            </GetInventoryStatusResult>
        </GetInventoryStatusResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

// $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*');

$names = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    $names[] = [
        'name' => $node->nodeName,
        'value' => $node->textContent,
    ];
}

print_r($names);
```

Comment: So that worked 75%! It gives me  `Array ( [0] => soap:Envelope [1] => soap:Body [2] => GetInventoryStatusResponse [3] => GetInventoryStatusResult [4] => MaterialCode [5] => MaterialDescription [6] => QuantityOnHand [7] => QuantityAllocated [8] => QuantityAvailable [9] => QuantityOnOrder [10] => QuantityInProduction [11] => ReorderQuantity [12] => ReorderLevel [13] => DesiredLevel )`

Comment: It does not give me the quantity inside the bracket. So for example, MaterialCode is 10029