# How convert xml with namespaces to php array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I Can't figure out how to convert this xmlstring to php array despite reading many posts.

SimpleXML does not work, creates only a empty object.

My target is to álways extract the first `<value xmlns="">1.01655E1</value>` found.

CODE:
`$arr = new SimpleXmlElement($xml); print_r($arr);`

RESULT:
`SimpleXMLElement Object ( )`

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse xmlns:ns0="http://swea.riksbank.se/xsd">
            <return xmlns="">
                <datefrom xmlns="">2022-08-04</datefrom>
                <dateto xmlns="">2022-08-10</dateto>
                <groups xmlns="">
                    <groupid xmlns="">130</groupid>
                    <groupname xmlns="">Currencies against Swedish kronor</groupname>
                    <series xmlns="">
                        <seriesid xmlns="">SEKUSDPMI</seriesid>
                        <seriesname xmlns="">1 USD</seriesname>
                        <unit xmlns="">1.0E0</unit>
                        <resultrows xmlns="">
                            <date xmlns="">2022-08-04</date>
                            <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <value xmlns="">1.01997E1</value>
                        </resultrows>
                        <resultrows xmlns="">
                            <date xmlns="">2022-08-05</date>
                            <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <value xmlns="">1.01279E1</value>
                        </resultrows>
                        <resultrows xmlns="">
                            <date xmlns="">2022-08-08</date>
                            <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <value xmlns="">1.01655E1</value>
                        </resultrows>
                        <resultrows xmlns="">
                            <date xmlns="">2022-08-09</date>
                            <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <value xmlns="">1.01517E1</value>
                        </resultrows>
                        <resultrows xmlns="">
                            <date xmlns="">2022-08-10</date>
                            <period xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <min xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <average xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <max xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <ultimo xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" ns1:nil="true"/>
                            <value xmlns="">1.0173E1</value>
                        </resultrows>
                    </series>
                </groups>
            </return>
        </ns0:getInterestAndExchangeRatesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is getting frustrating ;)
Big thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you looking for the first `<value xmlns="">` element in order to extract `1.01655E1` from it?

Comment: Yes, thats my need in this application. But generally the main issue is how to create a php array from the entire xml content? I have only user API's with JSON response before, with great success.

Comment: The solution is almost certainly *not to convert it to an array* - PHP arrays just aren't the same "shape" as XML documents, so you'll always run into confusion. Instead, *get the data you need* using the functionality that SimpleXML provides. Specifically, see [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei)

Comment: This is SOAP - PHP has an [extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the issue is exactly, but with this:

```
$arr = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$target = ($arr->xpath('//*[local-name()="value"]')[0]);
echo($target);
```

you can get

```
1.01997E1
```

and if you're interested in, for example, the third `<value>` element, it's just:

```
$target = ($arr->xpath('//*[local-name()="value"]')[2]);
echo($target);
```

which returns

```
1.01655E1
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find a solution and now it works!

(Even tho it is not a conversion of the XML-content to an array, as i do with JSON-content. )