# How can I parse XML data to array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I'm not to experienced with XML and I have been trying to figure this out without to much progress.

I need to get the results from the XML file to a array using PHP.

Here is the XML

```
<ns2:messageContainer xmlns="datex2.eu/schema/3/common" xmlns:ns2="datex2.eu/schema/3/messageContainer" xmlns:ns3="datex2.eu/schema/3/exchangeInformation" xmlns:ns4="datex2.eu/schema/3/informationManagement" xmlns:ns5="datex2.eu/schema/3/dataDictionaryExtension" xmlns:ns6="datex2.eu/schema/3/cctvExtension" xmlns:ns7="datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing" xmlns:ns8="datex2.eu/schema/3/alertCLocationCodeTableExtension" xmlns:ns9="datex2.eu/schema/3/extension" xmlns:ns10="datex2.eu/schema/3/roadTrafficData" xmlns:ns11="datex2.eu/schema/3/vms" xmlns:ns12="datex2.eu/schema/3/situation" modelBaseVersion="3">
    <ns2:payload xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns7:PredefinedLocationsPublication" lang="no" modelBaseVersion="3">
        <publicationTime>2023-01-25T13:56:15.615+01:00</publicationTime>
        <publicationCreator>
            <country>no</country>
            <nationalIdentifier>NPRA</nationalIdentifier>
        </publicationCreator>
        <ns7:headerInformation>
            <confidentiality>noRestriction</confidentiality>
            <informationStatus>real</informationStatus>
        </ns7:headerInformation>

        <ns7:predefinedLocationReference xsi:type="ns7:PredefinedLocation" id="100356" version="1">
            <ns7:predefinedLocationName>
                <values>
                    <value lang="no">Eikås - Åsanevegen</value>
                </values>
            </ns7:predefinedLocationName>
            <ns7:location xsi:type="ns7:LinearLocation">
                <ns7:gmlLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32633">
                    <ns7:posList>-27946 6743813</ns7:posList>
                </ns7:gmlLineString>
            </ns7:location>
        </ns7:predefinedLocationReference>
        <ns7:predefinedLocationReference xsi:type="ns7:PredefinedLocation" id="100361" version="1">
            <ns7:predefinedLocationName>
                <values>
                    <value lang="no">Ammerud - Bjerke</value>
                </values>
            </ns7:predefinedLocationName>
            <ns7:location xsi:type="ns7:LinearLocation">
                <ns7:gmlLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32633">
                    <ns7:posList>269553 6653843</ns7:posList>
                </ns7:gmlLineString>
            </ns7:location>
        </ns7:predefinedLocationReference>
    </ns2:payload>
    <ns2:exchangeInformation modelBaseVersion="3">
        <ns3:exchangeContext>
            <ns3:codedExchangeProtocol>snapshotPull</ns3:codedExchangeProtocol>
            <ns3:exchangeSpecificationVersion>3</ns3:exchangeSpecificationVersion>
            <ns3:supplierOrCisRequester>
                <ns3:internationalIdentifier>
                    <country>no</country>
                    <nationalIdentifier>NPRA</nationalIdentifier>
                </ns3:internationalIdentifier>
            </ns3:supplierOrCisRequester>
        </ns3:exchangeContext>
        <ns3:dynamicInformation>
            <ns3:exchangeStatus>undefined</ns3:exchangeStatus>
            <ns3:messageGenerationTimestamp>2023-01-25T13:56:15.615+01:00</ns3:messageGenerationTimestamp>
        </ns3:dynamicInformation>
    </ns2:exchangeInformation>
</ns2:messageContainer>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response->raw_body, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA, 'ns2', true);
        
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns7','http://datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing');

        $count = 0;
        foreach($xml->xpath('//ns7:predefinedLocationReference') as $event) {

            $return[$count]['id'] = intval($event->attributes()->id);
            $predefinedLocationName = $event->xpath('ns7:predefinedLocationName');
            foreach ($predefinedLocationName[0]->values as $locVal) {
                $return[$count]['name'] = strval($locVal->value);
            }

            $count++;
        }
```

I'm sure there is a better way but here is what I got:

```
            {
                "id": 100356,
                "name": "Eikås - Åsanevegen"
            },
            {
                "id": 100361,
                "name": "Ammerud - Bjerke"
            }
```

What I'm missing is to get out the posList value from the XML and add it to my array in PHP

Comment: What exactly is making this element difficult for you to get? There are certainly other ways of writing the whole code, but you should be able to get the posList in much the same way as you get the name.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to use someone else's meaningless prefixes like "ns7" to refer to namespaces - and probably shouldn't, because those look auto-generated and likely to change in future, leaving you in a muddle where your "ns7" is now the document's "ns6". Give them an alias that makes sense to you, like `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('locRef','http://datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing');`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @IMSoP. Whatever I try I get an empty posList.

Comment: Your main problem is that `value` and `postList` are in different namespaces and you need to declare them both. Also, I would use DOMDocument instead, because (among other reason) of its better xpath and namespace support.

Comment: @JackFleeting Obviously, tastes vary, but I find the DOM extremely verbose and fiddly, and wouldn't bother with XPath for this problem in the first place. SimpleXML has some parts that aren't obvious at first, but once you understand those, it does mostly live up to its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than messing around with XPath, I would use the main SimpleXML access methods, noting [this reference of how SimpleXML handles namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894426/157957).

Specifically, I would note down the path I wanted to take through the document, expanding namespaces to their full identifiers rather than their local aliases:

- Start at `messageContainer`, in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/messageContainer` namespace
- Go into `payload`, in the same namespace
- Loop over each `predefinedLocationReference`, in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing` namespace
- Get the "id" from the (non-namespaced) `id` attribute
- Go into `predefinedLocationName`, still in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing` namespace
- Go into `values`, in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/common` namespace (defined as the default `xmlns` at the top of the document)
- Get the "name" from the `value` element in that namespace
- From the `predefinedLocationReference` we had earlier, go into the `location` (in the same namespace as `predefinedLocationReference`)
- Go into `gmlLineString`, in the same namespace
- Get the "postList" from the `posList`, in the same namespace

That then translates directly to this PHP code:

```php
// Some constants to make namespaces easier to read
const NS_MSG_CONT = 'datex2.eu/schema/3/messageContainer';
const NS_LOC_REF = 'datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing';
const NS_COMMON = 'datex2.eu/schema/3/common';

// Initialise our return array
$return = [];

// Start at `messageContainer`, in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/messageContainer` namespace
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response->raw_body, "SimpleXMLElement", 0, NS_MSG_CONT);

// Go into `payload`, in the same namespace
$payload = $xml->payload;

// Loop over each `predefinedLocationReference`, in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing` namespace
foreach ($payload->children(NS_LOC_REF)->predefinedLocationReference as $predefinedLocationReference ) {
    // Initialise the return item
    $item = [];

    // Get the "id" from the (non-namespaced) `id` attribute
    $item['id'] = (string)$predefinedLocationReference->attributes(null)->id;

    // Go into `predefinedLocationName`, still in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing` namespace
    $predefinedLocationName = $predefinedLocationReference->predefinedLocationName;

    // Go into `values`, in the `datex2.eu/schema/3/common` namespace (defined as the default `xmlns` at the top of the document)
    $values = $predefinedLocationName->children(NS_COMMON)->values;

    // Get the "name" from the `value` element in that namespace
    $item['name'] = (string)$values->value;

    // From the `predefinedLocationReference` we had earlier, go into the `location` (in the same namespace as `predefinedLocationReference`)
    $location = $predefinedLocationReference->location;

    // Go into `gmlLineString`, in the same namespace
    $gmlLineString = $location->gmlLineString;

    // Get the "posList" from the `posList`, in the same namespace
    $item['posList'] = (string)$gmlLineString->posList;

    // Add item to our final results
    $return[] = $item;
}

// Test
var_dump($return);
```

This can obviously be made much shorter by removing comments and intermediate variables to taste; a very shortened version of exactly the same code looks like this:

```php
const NS_MSG_CONT = 'datex2.eu/schema/3/messageContainer';
const NS_LOC_REF = 'datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing';
const NS_COMMON = 'datex2.eu/schema/3/common';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($raw_body, "SimpleXMLElement", 0, NS_MSG_CONT);
// Note: in PHP >8.0, you can skip the parameters you're not interested in:
// $xml = simplexml_load_string($raw_body, namespace_or_prefix: NS_MSG_CONT);
$return = [];
foreach ($xml->payload->children(NS_LOC_REF)->predefinedLocationReference as $predefinedLocationReference ) {
    $return[] = [
        'id' => (string)$predefinedLocationReference->attributes(null)->id,
        'name' => (string)$predefinedLocationReference->predefinedLocationName->children(NS_COMMON)->values->value,
        'posList' => (string)$predefinedLocationReference->location->gmlLineString->posList,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @IMSoP for this. Works exactly as I wanted!

Comment: As you say in your comment above, tastes indeed vary; but while I'm still firmly in the xpath/domdoc camp, I must say your short form answer is a thing of beauty!