# CURL output in an array - simplexml_load_string not working

Tags: php, json, xml, curl

There are many posting on this subject. Having worked on this problem for a day and not found a solution so I am reaching out.

I have looked at posting and I cannot see what I am doing wrong:

[Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei)

This code is calling a API using WSDL

```
$url = "https://test.domian.com/rrpservices/checkDomainsService";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array (
    "Content-Type: text/xml"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:checkDomains>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <user>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>userxxxxx</name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <password>xxxxxx</password>
         </user>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <check>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <name>teddy12345678.com.cn</name>
            <name>teddyabc.com.cn</name>
            <name>google.com</name>
         </check>
      </ws:checkDomains>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);    
curl_close($curl);
```

To be able to see the output I have to use;

```
echo "<pre>". htmlentities($resp) . "</pre>";
```

This gives me;

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns1:checkDomainsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws/"><response><result code="200"><msg>check domain return</msg></result><domains><domain avail="1"><name>teddy12345678.com.cn</name></domain><domain avail="1"><name>teddyabc.com.cn</name></domain><domain avail="0"><name>google.com</name></domain></domains></response></ns1:checkDomainsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

While this data looks like XML string, I believe it to be RAW data string as the standard code for processing XML data does not work. e.g.

```
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($resp);      
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xmlObject),TRUE);
print_r ($array);
```

This creates no output. simplexml_load_string us not working

I wish to create XML and/or an array from this data.

Any ideas would be very welcome

Thanks, Pete

Comment: Don't use that `json_decode(json_encode(...))` hack. Ever. Blindly converting XML to a PHP array is generally not what you want anyway; what you want is to *retrieve the data you're interested in*, using the API provided by SimpleXML (or, if you prefer, DOM). That requires a bit of understanding of XML, but it's not so bad once you get the hang of it.

Comment: If you copy/paste that exact response into a service such as [Code Beautify](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer) it appears to be valid XML

Comment: I agree, the format is XML. When paste for out into Code Beautify, all is good. It is my PHP code that is at fault, I just cannot see the problem.

Comment: As pointed out the use of `json_decode(json_encode(...))` is a very ropey, unreliable method for parsing XML - use the correct tools for the job and it should all be fine. I've never use the `SimpleXML` suite of tools so can offer no guidance but DOMDocument & DOMXPath are simple to learn, reliable and pwerful when used correctly

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Just to be clear, the `json_decode(json_encode(...))` trick doesn't actually attempt to _parse_ the XML, it just takes a perfectly good object (the result of `simplexml_load_string`) and throws away all of its functionality, and a bunch of the content.

Comment: @Pete As I said in my first comment, the problem is that you are trying to blindly convert the XML to an array. That's just not going to work, delete the lines referring to `$array`, and work directly with `$xmlObject`, which is what the linked question is describing. Here's a quick demo: https://3v4l.org/CS9jB

Comment: @IMSoP fair play, as I say - I've never used simplexml so no idea what `simplexml_load_string` does/returns.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius For access to data in a reasonably structured XML document, it really lives up to its name, and is much simpler than the equivalent DOM code. Interestingly, the actual parsing is shared between DOM and SimpleXML; you can even switch between them without reparsing: https://www.php.net/simplexml_import_dom and https://www.php.net/dom_import_simplexml

Comment: While there are many articles on this matter. This type of array is object based. All parts of the array has to be addressed by its field names;  $msg = $responce_param->response->result->msg;  $code = $responce_param->response->result->code;  or  foreach($responce_param->response->records->record as $a) {
  echo '<p>Host = ' .$a->host. ', '; 
  echo 'Type = ' .$a->type. ', '; 
  echo 'Value = ' .$a->value. '</p>'; 
  } Hope this helps