# Handling SimpleXMl with colon in namespace and no colon in children/child element

Tags: php, soap, xml-parsing, simplexml, php-curl

I have an XMl output that seems a bit different from examples I've seeing for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei),which was the closest I've been to understanding how to access the xml.

I need to able to access "e_datos" to get all element and able to access specific child element example "telf1".

I'm failing to be able to get the build the syntax properly. To many issues with the way my xml is build, my urn is on another level from my namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

```
$xml = <<<XML
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:header>
   <soap-env:body>
      <n0:zfi_mf_ws_consulta_clienteresponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
         <e_datos>
            <kunnrdf>123</kunnrdf>
            <name1>name</name1>
            <land1>VE</land1>
            <stras>street</stras>
            <ort01>SAN FRANCISCO</ort01>
            <telf1>0261-215012</telf1>
            <stcd1>J-0701721725-7</stcd1>
            <stcd1_sg>J07017252252177</stcd1_sg>
            <smtp_addr>test@hotmail.com</smtp_addr>
            <tatyp_1>Flete</tatyp_1>
            <taxkd_1>0</taxkd_1>
            <tatyp_2>Producto</tatyp_2>
            <taxkd_2>1</taxkd_2>
         </e_datos>
         <e_respuesta>
            <tipo>
               <clase>
                  <nro>000</nro>
                  <mensaje />
               </clase>
            </tipo>
         </e_respuesta>
      </n0:zfi_mf_ws_consulta_clienteresponse>
   </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:header>
</soap-env:envelope>
XML;
```

How can I adapt this when my XML output is not the same, this was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei)

```
  $xml = 
<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document xmlns="http://example.com" 
  xmlns:ns2="https://namespaces.example.org/two" xmlns:seq="urn:example:sequences">
    <list type="short">
        <ns2:item seq:position="1">A thing</ns2:item>
        <ns2:item seq:position="2">Another thing</ns2:item>
    </list>
</document>
XML;
 $sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);

   define('XMLNS_EG1', 'http://example.com');
  define('XMLNS_EG2', 'https://namespaces.example.org/two');
   define('XMLNS_SEQ', 'urn:example:sequences');

    foreach ( $sx->children(XMLNS_EG1)->list->children(XMLNS_EG2)->item as $item ) {
echo 'Position: ' . $item->attributes(XMLNS_SEQ)->position . "\n";
echo 'Item: ' . (string)$item . "\n";
     }
```