# Parse xml child and namespace with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to read a specific xml child from the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <exp:Input xmlns:exp="http://exportservice.domest.sogei.it">
            <exp:serviceId>Send item text</exp:serviceId>
            <exp:data>
                <exp:xml>textcontent</exp:xml>
                <exp:dichiarante>AXB17735</exp:dichiarante>
            </exp:data>
        </exp:Input>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

what i need is to read the child SERVICEID

I tried with xpath but no solution... any help?
I saw that some of you used the array...

Thanks

I would like to avoid the array and use a simple call to the child exp:serviceid... Possible?

Comment: The conventional solution is [SOAP extension](https://php.net/soap). Is that an option for you? (Update: well, of course, you still have namespaces in response body).

Comment: any help how to use it? Maybe an example?

Comment: Namespace handling examples at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei . Regarding SOAP, I'm sure there're tutorials if you don't understand the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <exp:Input xmlns:exp="http://exportservice.domest.sogei.it">
            <exp:serviceId>Send item text</exp:serviceId>
            <exp:data>
                <exp:xml>textcontent</exp:xml>
                <exp:dichiarante>AXB17735</exp:dichiarante>
            </exp:data>
        </exp:Input>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$namespaces = $xmlObject->getNamespaces(true); // get namespaces

// Navigate through the XML
$body = $xmlObject->children($namespaces['soapenv'])->Body;
$input = $body->children($namespaces['exp'])->Input;

$serviceId = (string) $input->serviceId;
$data = $input->data->children($namespaces['exp']);
$xmlContent = (string) $data->xml;
$dichiarante = (string) $data->dichiarante;

echo "Service ID: $serviceId\n";
echo "XML Content: $xmlContent\n";
echo "Dichiarante: $dichiarante\n";
?>
```

> Check this  code

Comment: Error: Cannot create object

Comment: any help on this example> This could help me much. thanks a lot friends

Comment: @dv2023it79 i have  updated the code please check  now

Comment: i only have problems if i want to read the same xml file from the server by using 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml")

Comment: I read that with loaded file it's not allowe your example... we should use xpath... any help ?

Comment: any help on this please?

Comment: Please explain how your code works.

Comment: when i use simplexml_load_string it works but the xml file is embedded into the page (as a var). What i want is to be able to load xml file from the server... so i use simplexml_load_file()... but when i use it it says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function registerXPathNamespace() on bool"