# Read XML feed with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, feed, file-get-contents

I have a problem with I trying to read and parse this feed:
Some XML Feed

for some reason the function SimpleXMLElement returns empty nodes. I am using file_get_contents to read the URL and then SimpleXMLElement.

Here an example:

```
<?php
// URL feed XML
$url = 'some xml feed';

$xml_content = file_get_contents($url);

if ($xml_content === false) {
    echo "No XML content.";
    exit;
}

// Parser the XML
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_content);


foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = (string) $item->title;
    $id = (string) $item->{'cnn-article:id'};
    $description = (string) $item->description;

    // Hacer lo que necesites con los datos
    echo "Title: $title<br>";
    echo "ID: $id<br>";
    echo "Description: $description<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure, I think is my php version. Thanks.

Comment: Without a [mre] in the question itself, it's hard to answer properly. For general tips, see [Reference - How do I handle Namespaces (Tags and Attributes with a Colon in their Name) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-a-colon-in-thei)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML doesn't handle XML namespaces (i.e., tags with colons) ideally, so you can't do this unfortunately:

```php
$id = (string) $item->{'cnn-article:id'};
```

You should be able to grab the field by using the [children()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) selector and passing a truthy value as the second parameter:

```php
$id = (string) $item->children('cnn-article', true)->id;
```

Or perhaps, if you're going to use a bunch of the fields within that tag:

```php
$cnn = $item->children('cnn-article', true);
$id = (string) $cnn->id;
$url = (string) $cnn->url;
$slug = (string) $cnn->slug;
$createdDate = (string) $cnn->{'created-date'};
```

Comment: if this is the case .. Why does OP's script run OK on my `php` setup?  It correctly echos `Title` `ID` and `Description` -- `PHP 8.0` with  `libxml2 Version => 2.9.12`

Comment: The output posted in your comment does not include the ID.

Comment: Ahh I see what I did there ..  I saw the `<br>` and skipped the fact nothing was there --  Good to know!

Comment: The example depends on the namespace alias/prefix. This is optional and can change. A better solution is using the namespace URI. Look for the `xmlns:cnn-article` namespace definition. `$cnn = $item->children('http://...', false);`